# Get Session Status with Jquery

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc

In my application, I would know when the session has expired by doing Ajax calls every 30 seconds, but the problem is that when I can controller method, HttpSession refresh and lastaccessedtime changed.
So have you any idea how to know the status of the session without changing it's behaviour.
I'm using Jquery and SpringMVC 2.5

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/consultForm.htm", params = "verifySession", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView verifySessionStatus(WebRequest webRequest, Model model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    boolean isValid = true;
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
    if (session.getAttribute("user") == null) {
        isValid = false;
    }
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("jsonView");
    model.addAttribute("sessionValid", isValid);
    modelAndView.addObject(model);
    return modelAndView;
}


$.ajax({
    url : "search.htm?verifySession=1",
    type : "GET",
    async : false,
    cache : false,
    success : function(data) {

        valid = data.sessionValid;
        if (!valid) {
            showPopinExpire = true;
            $("#dialog-session-expired").dialog("open");
        }
    },
    error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
        alert(xhr.status);
        alert(thrownError);
    } 
});
```

Even with `request.isRequestedSessionIdValid()`, everytime I call controller method, the session was refreshed.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your example, it seems you want a json response as you are doing this:

```
valid = data.sessionValid;
```

It is not the **default** `dataType`, so you need to **specify** that:

```
$.ajax({
    url : "search.htm?verifySession=1",
    type : "GET",
    async : false,
    cache : false,
    dataType: 'json' // added this
    // your rest of the code
```

Comment: The problem is that in my controller, when I get the session, it was refreshed and lastaccessedtime was updated! Have you any idea to keep it?

Comment: When I call the session in my controller, the lastAccessedTime changed. Is there any way to keep it when I do Ajax call? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use timer in Javascript to count the time for session to expire, and have register [ajaxSend](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSend/) handler to reset the timer.

Comment: When I call the session in my controller, the lastAccessedTime changed. Is there any way to keep it when I do Ajax call? Thanks

Comment: @Mohamed In php every time you call your script with ajax your session timer set is reset. For instance if you don't want session to expire you can call ajax request in interval.

Answer (score 1):

Everytime you will make a request to the server, the session lastAccessedTime will be updated.

What you can do is store a timestamp a custom variable in the session everytime you want to. Then using your ajax, you could call a controller's method to retreive that custom timestamp that was stored in your object. I would suggest you to use an AOP method to generate your timestamp. I will be less intrusive.

Good luck !